# Show rows in dynamic table based on a parameter in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ant-design-vue

I have an ant design table in vue rendered dynamically based on a API data response(`:data-source="table_deployenv_data"`):

```
<a-table :data-source="table_deployenv_data" :columns="columnsdeployenvs" bordered>
</a-table>
```

Columns are defined as following:

```
columnsdeployenvs: [
        {
          title: "ID",
          dataIndex: "id",
          key: "id",
        },
        {
          title: "Env",
          dataIndex: "env",
          key: "env",
          scopedSlots: {
            filterDropdown: "filterDropdown",
            filterIcon: "filterIcon",
            customRender: "customRender",
          },
          onFilter: (value, record) =>
            record.env.toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
          onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
            if (visible) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.searchInput.focus();
              }, 0);
            }
          },
          sorter: (a, b) => a.modulename.localeCompare(b.moduleame),
          sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
        },
        {
        .......
```

Now I have an env parameter passed in: `{{ $route.params.id}}` and I want to **ONLY** display the table rows when the value of **id** column equals to `{{ $route.params.id}}`.

So far I've tried using v-show, style with display: none but none of them is working, does anyone knows an elegant way to do this? I'm really new to front end programming so don't know much about Vue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a computed list

```
computed: {
  table_deployenv_data_filtered: {
    get: function () {
      return this.table_deployenv_data_filtered.filter(p=>p.id==$route.params.id);
    }



  
  }
}


<a-table :data-source="table_deployenv_data_filtered" :columns="columnsdeployenvs" bordered>
    </a-table>
```

**Alternative**

in data section add

```
table_deployenv_data_filtered=[]
```

in mounted method

```
this.table_deployenv_data_filtered = this.table_deployenv_data.filter(p=>p.id==this.$route.params.id);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried it but the entire section got blank. The error is `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ...  at VueComponent.computedGetter [as table_deployenv_data_filtered]`. It looks like the filtered data is too large. Is it possible to split the filtered data source for rendering?

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded --> threre is a loop is some point . (alterenative: declare a local variable table_deployenv_data_filtered, remove computed, assign table_deployenv_data_filtered in "mouted" method),... correct method is "filter" (previous has a typo)

Comment: Thanks! I changed removed `computed`, added it to mounted and it worked really well: `this.table_deployenv_data_filtered = this.table_deployenv_data.filter(p=>p.id==this.$route.params.id);` :)